# How to use EVERY to locate all items that have this property set to FALSE

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using the EVERY method on a Select all feature in my project.

As an onChange listener on my checkboxes my function runs this code to see if the value of canWrite on each object is set to true/false

```
checkSelected() {

  let testWrite = this.modalData.columnPermissions.every(function (item) 
    return item.canWrite;
  });

  this.isEveryWriteSelected = testWrite;

}
```

However, the scope of the model has changed to include an additional property "IDM=true/false"- IDM items cannot be selected so presently this listening code now never fires true.

I am trying to adapt my function to now only check canWrite=true if the item contains IDM=false

Am I able to use EVERY in this situation by ignoring item.IDM=false?

Have tried adding an if statement as a test, but this hasn't resolved my issue

```
let testWrite = this.modalData.columnPermissions.every(function (item) {
  if (!item.IDM) {
    return item.canWrite;
  }
});
```

MY HTML - which is Angular 2 can be seen below:

This is the select all checkbox which is listening for isEveryWriteSelected

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1c" [(ngModel)]="isEveryWriteSelected" name="isEveryWriteSelected" (change)="selectAll('Write', isEveryWriteSelected)" [disabled]="modalData.role != 1 || roleConfirm">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1c"><span>Select All</span></label>
</div>
```

while each rendered checkbox has an on change event calling the above function

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngIf="!column.IDM">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck{{column.$id}}-write" name="customCheck{{column.$id}}-write" [(ngModel)]="column.canWrite" [checked]="column.canWrite" [disabled]="modalData.role != 1 || roleConfirm" (change)="checkSelected()">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{column.$id}}-write"><span class="hideMe">&nbsp;</span></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share your html code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all items with `IDM=true` first and then run an [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on the rest of the items.

This (in my opinion) will make your code more readable for the next developer.

```js
const modalData = {
  columnPermissions: [
    {IDM: true, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: false, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: true, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: false, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: true, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: false, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: true, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: false, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: false, canWrite: true},
    {IDM: true, canWrite: true},
  ]
}

const checkSelected = () => {
  let testWrite = modalData.columnPermissions
                  .filter(({ IDM }) => !IDM)
                  .every(({ canWrite }) => !!canWrite)

  console.log(testWrite)

}
checkSelected()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to check all items which have either `canWrite` `true` or `IDM` `true`

```
let testWrite = this.modalData.columnPermissions.every(function (item) {
    return item.canWrite || item.IDM;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your final result is only based on items where IDM is false, you should first filter all items with such property. And then the original logic with `every` would work fine.

Example code:

```
return this.modalData.columnPermissions
.filter(function (item) {
  return item.IDM === false;
})
.every(function (item) {
    return item.canWrite;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close when you had this idea:

```
let testWrite = this.modalData.columnPermissions.every(function (item) {
  if (!item.IDM) {
    return item.canWrite;
  }
});
```

All you have to do is return true in the else clause for items with IDM set to true:

```
let testWrite = this.modalData.columnPermissions.every(function (item) {
  if (!item.IDM) {
    return item.canWrite;
  }
  // else...
  return true;
});
```

The reason for doing that is, by returning true, only the items with IDM set to false will be able to effect the final result and potentially turn it false by returning false in the predicate statement.